# How to avoid warning about no return expression when using static_assert?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-warnings

I have two libraries that I work with and I wrote a converter between some of the types/structs they use, for convenience.

```
template<typename T>
struct unsupportedType : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T>
FormatB getFormat()
{
    static_assert(
        unsupportedType<T>::value, "This is not supported!");
}

template<>
FormatB getFormat<FormatA::type1>()
{
    return FormatB(//some parameters);
}

template<>
FormatB getFormat<FormatA::type2>()
{
    return FormatB(//some other parameters);
}
```

Now due to the `unsupportedType` struct, the compiler does not immediately see that the assertion will always fail and thus does not throw a compilation error if the non-specialized version is not called somewhere. However, the compiler therefore also does not know that a return statement after the `static_assert` is unnecessary. I do not just want to place an arbitrary return statement after the assert to get rid of the warning.

**Question:** What is a clean way to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Have you tried the C++ attribute `[[noreturn]]` on the function declaration?

Comment: What's wrong with just putting `return` after static assert?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour when the static_assert fails? The reason the compiler warns is that there are ways to break the static_assert (specializing the `unsupportedType` struct).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would try to avoid the static_assert, by using something like

```
template<typename T> FormatB getFormat()=delete;
```

The compiler writers can then work on improving those error messages.

Comment: This actually does not answer the question directly, but it gives the best answer to my actual problem, I guess, how to not allow the non specialized version to be called. I don't know if I should now reformulate the question, or how to proceed to make this question + answer the most useful to everyone.

Comment: Somehow I missed the elephant in the room.

Comment: While this is legal code, at least one compiler (clang) will reject it.

Answer (score 6):

There's more than one way to exit a function, `return`ing is one, but `throw`ing is another:

```
template<typename T>
FormatB getFormat()
{
    static_assert(
        unsupportedType<T>::value, "This is not supported!");
    throw 0; // Unreachable
}
```

Comment: Is it considered good practice to just throw `0`? I could imagine that if for some reason somebody is "clever" enough to specialize `unsupportedType` giving it a true value, it might be hard to track if it just throws an arbitrary `0`.

Comment: @MrZ that throw is unreachable, it'll never actually happen. It's there to make the compiler think that the function always finished execution in well-defined manner (because for the compiler the static_assert is not guaranteed to fire).

Comment: @MrZ then I suggest `throw std::runtime_error{"Why the hell are you trying to break my TMP?"};` ;)

Comment: @MrZ in the words of...someone, "Guard against Murphy, not Machiavelli"

Comment: Ok. I guess with a descriptive `runtime_error` this is good enough for me.

Comment: @Quentin, and as you mentioned the removing of the return type does not work for all compilers. So mine (gcc 6.1) complains. For which compiler does it actually work, do you know?

Comment: @W.F. no, no we can't. I must have mixed that up with something else...

Comment: @MrZ I know you've decided on the other answer, but future visitors here might want a `logic_error` instead: succeeding in calling a function that *should* issue a compile error indicates an error in the program logic, after all

Comment: @jaggedSpire True, runtime_error is misleading in this case, I agree.

Answer (score 6):

For you said in a comment to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40682142/4987285) that it *actually does not answer the question directly*, here is a working solution that can be of help for future readers.

---

To solve the *issue* you can just define your function template as it follows:

```
template<typename T, typename R = void>
R getFormat()
{
    static_assert(
        unsupportedType<T>::value, "This is not supported!");
}
```

No changes are required for the other specializations, the type `R` can be deduced directly from the return type.

---

It follows a minimal, working example that shows how it works:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct unsupportedType : std::false_type
{};

struct FormatA{
    using type1 = int;
    using type2 = char;
};

struct FormatB{};

template<typename T, typename R = void>
R getFormat()
{
    static_assert(
        unsupportedType<T>::value, "This is not supported!");
}

template<>
FormatB getFormat<FormatA::type1>()
{
    return FormatB();
}

template<>
FormatB getFormat<FormatA::type2>()
{
    return FormatB();
}

int main() {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use GCC's [`__builtin_unreachable`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (it's way down on that link) to communicate to the compiler that a given line is unreachable, which will suppress that warning. (I mostly mention this for C devs who end up here; for C++, the method using `delete` above is better).